# AspNetCoreRateLimit Does not use query parameters when matching rules

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, throttling, rate-limiting

I'm using [AspNetCoreRateLimit](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit) library with Asp.Net Core 2.2 web api. I've taken IpRateLimiting into use with it's default settings in `Startup.cs` as seen [AspNetCoreRateLimit wiki](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/IpRateLimitMiddleware).

I have API endpoint with query parameters, and it is used with http GET queries as following (see parameters `startDate` and `stopDate`):

```
GET "https://host/api/endpoint/path?startDate=2020-04-04&stopDate=2020-04-04"
```

I want to limit only **unique** requests (with unique parameter combinations) to 5 requests per hour. So, for example, the following scenario should be possible in 1 hour:

```
5 times: GET "https://host/api/endpoint/path?startDate=2020-04-04&stopDate=2020-04-04"
5 times: GET "https://host/api/endpoint/path?startDate=2020-04-05&stopDate=2020-04-05"
```

The problem is that I can send only **total** 5 requests per hour regardless of parameters.

Following is my IpRateLimiting Settings from appsettings.json.

```
"IpRateLimiting": {
    "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": true,
    "StackBlockedRequests": false,
    "RealIPHeader": "X-Real-IP",
    "ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
    "HttpStatusCode": 429,
    "GeneralRules": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "*:/api/endpoint/path",
        "Period": "1h",
        "Limit": 5
      }
    ]
  }
```

Please note, that I don't want to change the endpoint route as proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61792298/5789864) good answer by *@Yongqing Yu*, because there are a bunch of API clients out there using my API and I do not want to introduce any breaking changes.

Comment: probably you need a custom resolver, take a look here: https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/IpRateLimitMiddleware#defining-rate-limit-rules

Comment: @alessandro I'll try this..

Comment: @alessandro this works, and I made it as whole answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution and thus answering to myself. In my case I am not able to change the controller method route as proposed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61792298/5789864).

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/IpRateLimitMiddleware#defining-rate-limit-rules) it is possible to implement own path extraction logic. I wrote custom IpRateLimitMiddleware and overrided ResolveIdentity-method as follows:

```
public class CustomIpRateLimitMiddleware : IpRateLimitMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger<CustomIpRateLimitMiddleware> _logger;
    private readonly IRateLimitConfiguration _config;

    public CustomIpRateLimitMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,
        IOptions<IpRateLimitOptions> options,
        IRateLimitCounterStore counterStore,
        IIpPolicyStore policyStore,
        IRateLimitConfiguration config,
        ILogger<CustomIpRateLimitMiddleware> logger)
    : base(next, options, counterStore, policyStore, config, logger)

    {
        _config = config;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override ClientRequestIdentity ResolveIdentity(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var identity = base.ResolveIdentity(httpContext);

        if (httpContext.Request.Query == null && !httpContext.Request.Query.Any())
        {
            return identity;
        }

        StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(httpContext.Request.Path.ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
        foreach (var parameter in httpContext.Request.Query)
        {
            path.Append("/" + parameter.Value);
        }
        identity.Path = path.ToString();
        return identity;
    }
}
```

And this is initialized in Startup.cs as following:

`ConfigureServices`-method:

```
services.AddOptions();
services.AddMemoryCache();
services.Configure<IpRateLimitOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("IpRateLimiting"));
services.AddSingleton<IIpPolicyStore, MemoryCacheIpPolicyStore>();
services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitCounterStore, MemoryCacheRateLimitCounterStore>();
services.AddSingleton<IRateLimitConfiguration, RateLimitConfiguration>();
```

`Configure`-method:

```
app.UseMiddleware<CustomIpRateLimitMiddleware>();
```

The code snippet above amends query for the middleware so it looks like those query parameters are part of the path.

So instead of this:

```
/api/endpoint/path?startDate=2020-04-04&stopDate=2020-04-04"
```

AspNetCoreRateLimit is getting path as following format:

```
/api/endpoint/path/2020-04-04/2020-04-04
```

..and now my rate limiting configuration can be this:

```
"IpRateLimiting": {
    "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": true,
    "StackBlockedRequests": false,
    "RealIPHeader": "X-Real-IP",
    "ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
    "HttpStatusCode": 429,
    "GeneralRules": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "*:/api/path/*",
        "Period": "1h",
        "Limit": 5
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: And how did you use the Custom middleware, did you register the middleware on StartUp?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I imagine you replaced this line
app.UseIpRateLimiting(); with this one app.UseMiddleware<CustomIpRateLimitMiddleware>();

Comment: Thats right, since I made my own Middleware. There is now that whole class CustomIpRateLimitMiddleware in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can `change the route` of the corresponding action and turn the parameter directly into a part of the path like `'https://host/api/endpoint/path/2020-04-04/2020-04-04'`, so that the `Endpoint` in `GeneralRules` can satisfy your condition by `*`.

You can refer to [this](https://edi.wang/post/2019/6/16/ip-rate-limit-for-aspnet-core).

Here is my demo:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DefaultController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("Test/{startDate}/{stopDate}")]
    public string Test(string startDate, string stopDate)
    {
        return "Ok";
    }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
"IpRateLimiting": {
        "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": true,
        "StackBlockedRequests": false,
        "RealIPHeader": "X-Real-IP",
        "ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
        "HttpStatusCode": 429,
        "GeneralRules": [
          {
            "Endpoint": "*:/api/default/Test/*",
            "Period": "1h",
            "Limit": 5
          }
        ]
      }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. In my case changing controller method signature is a bit problematic because there are a bunch of API clients using my endpoint so I do not want to introduce any breaking changes.. I have to take a look if I can create a custom resolver.